# Topologies for graphs

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory

Some of the basic definitions in Graph theory made me wonder if there is by any chance a way to give a graph $G$ a topology, such that these definitions can be understood as versions of analogous definitions given in topology. For example, is there a topology for $G$ such that the definition of "connected graph" can be understood as equivalent to $G$ being a connected (or arc-connected) topological space?

Comment: Topology plays an important part in infinite graphs: Check out the chapter in R. Diestel's book "Graph Theory".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a notion of topological realization of a graph, basically given by taking points in $\Bbb R^n$ and gluing copies of the unit interval $[0,1]$ to it, wherever the graph has an edge. This results in a metric space.

Some results can be translated between this topological realization and the graph. For example the graph is connected, if and only if the realization is (path)-connected. Similarly the graph has a cycle, if and only if there is an embedding of a circle $\Bbb S^1$ into the realization etc.